# Implementing producer-consumer algorithm on a Raspberry Pi cluster

Tags: algorithm, cluster-computing, producer-consumer

I made a cluster using two raspberry pi's. I would like to implement producer consumer problem on this cluster. One of the pi's will increase the value and the other pi will decrease the value. Each raspberry pi's will run a thread. Where can I store the value variable?